# (python)stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping amazon products but in the first, I want to click on each category, the code work just with the first category in the loop and get this error, I searched about that and found many of answers but they didn't work inside the loop and all of them work with xpath(one element not elements)

first click (see_more) work, the problem with a click in loop

ERROR:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

Here is the code.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

from csv import writer

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Compu City\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')
time.sleep(10)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML", 'window.scrollBy(0,2000)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
cat=[]
filter_con = driver.find_element_by_id('widgetFilters')  # main container of products
cats=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label')
see_more =driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#widgetFilters > div:nth-child(1) > div.a-row.a-expander-container.a-expander-inline-container > a > span')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(filter_con).click(see_more).perform()
cat= 0
while(cat < len(cats)):
    print(cat)
    print(cats[cat].text)
    action = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(filter_con).click(cats[cat]).perform()
    cat+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you click on the `cat` element the references in the `cats` will be refreshed meaning selenium will get a new set of references to each elements. And as you are still pointing to the older references you are getting `Stale Element Exception`. Update your code as below.

Option 1: Fixing in existing code

```
while(cat < len(cats)):
    currentCat = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label')[cat]
    print(cat)
    print(currentCat.text)
    action = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(filter_con).click(currentCat).perform()
    cat+=1
```

Option 2: Using for loop (without action chain)

```
for catNumber in range(len(cats)):
    cat = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label')[catNumber+1]
    print(catNumber+1)
    # scroll to the elemen
    cat.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    # click
    cat.click()
```

Comment: I didn't get your comment., does it means the issue resolved?

Comment: ```driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.a-expander-container .a-checkbox label .a-label')[cat].click()``` the project worked with this line